# Setting a list item when clicked to be the Selected List

Tags: javascript

I accessed an array of objects from Local Storage,  dynamically created a li element from it and appended li elements into a ul element; each li element contains a className('list-name') and dataset. When an li element is clicked  a new className('active-list') which styles the element font-weight to bold is to be added and set its dataset value to a variable called selecetedUserId. 
Currently my code is not working corretly. Please i need assistance

```
HTML 
 <div class="accounts">
    <h2 class="accounts-title">My Users</h2>
    <ul class="userLists" user-data>
        <!-- <li class='list-item'>Yelmi Bulus</li> -->
    </ul>            
 </div>
 <div class="delete-stuff">
    <button class="btn delete">Delete user</button>
 </div>

JavaScript Codes
let userLists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));

/* data format in Local storage
  userLists = [
                {
                  id: 1583363448520, fullName: "Yelmi Bulus",  userAccountDetails:[]
                },
                {
                  id: 1583363467888, fullName: "Tobi Adesinya",userAccountDetails:[]
                }

              ]
*/


const userContainer = document.querySelector('[user-data]');
const deleteUserBtn = document.querySelector('.delete')
let userLists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
let selectedUserId = localStorage.getItem('selectedUserId');



function clearElement(element){
   while(element.firstChild){
       element.removeChild(element.firstChild)
   }
}    
function render(){
    clearElement(userContainer)
    userLists.forEach((user, index)=> {
        const userElement = document.createElement('li');
        userElement.dataset.userId = user.id
        userElement.classList.add("list-name");
        userElement.innerText = user.fullName
        if(user.id === selectedUserId){
            userElement.classList.add('active-user')
        }
        userContainer.appendChild(userElement)
    });
 }

function save(){
    render()
    localStorage.setItem('selectedUserId', selectedUserId)
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', saveAndRender)

userContainer.addEventListener('click', e=>{
   if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li'){
      selectedUserId = e.target.dataset.userId    
      saveAndRender()
   }

})

deleteUserBtn.addEventListener('click', e=>{
   userLists = userLists.filter(user => user.id !== selectedUserId)
   selectedUserId = null;
   saveAndRender()     
})
```

Comment: 'Currently my code is not working corretly.' Do you have any JS error?

Comment: i think `userContainer` is an array, so you need to loop and `addEventListener` to each

Comment: @Wimanicesir No. But it not functioning as inspected

Comment: Could you edit your question, What is not working? Add an expected result vs actual result.